# Routeenhancer typo3 extension with 2 plugin

Tags: typo3

I develop a Typo3 extension with 2 plugin

This is my ext_localconf.php

```
call_user_func(
    function()
    {

        \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
            'Didattica',
            'Lauree',
            [
                \Polimi\Didattica\Controller\ElencocdsController::class => 'lauree,detail',
            ],
            // non-cacheable actions
            [
                \Polimi\Didattica\Controller\ElencocdsController::class => 'lauree,detail',
            ]
        );

        \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
            'Didattica',
            'Laureemagistrali',
            [
                \Polimi\Didattica\Controller\ElencocdsmagController::class => 'laureemagistrali,detail',
            ],
            // non-cacheable actions
            [
                \Polimi\Didattica\Controller\ElencocdsmagController::class => 'laureemagistrali,detail',
            ]
        );
```

I tried to add a routeenhancer for my extension

```
routeEnhancers:
  Elencocds:
    type: Extbase
    extension: Didattica
    plugin: Lauree
    routes:
      - routePath: '{name}'
        _controller: 'Elencocds::detail'
        _arguments:
          name: elencocds
    defaultController: 'Elencocds::detail'
    defaults:
      page: '1'
    requirements:
      page: \d+
    aspects:
      name:
        type: PersistedPatternMapper
        tableName: tx_didattica_domain_model_elencocds
        routeFieldPattern: ^(?<slug>.+)$
        routeFieldResult: '{slug}'

  Elencocdsmag:
    type: Extbase
    extension: Didattica
    plugin: Laureemagistrali
    routes:
      - routePath: '{name}'
        _controller: 'Elencocdsmag::detail'
        _arguments:
          name: elencocds
    defaultController: 'Elencocdsmag::detail'
    defaults:
      page: '1'
    requirements:
      page: \d+
    aspects:
      name:
        type: PersistedPatternMapper
        tableName: tx_didattica_domain_model_elencocds
        routeFieldPattern: ^(?<slug>.+)$
        routeFieldResult: '{slug}'
```

the first plugin works fine.

the second plugin correctly displays the "converted" url, but remains stationary in the "laureemagistrali" action, and does not apply the "detail" action.
Seems it does not nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't use `page` in your `routePath` so you can remove that. For simplicity, you can use `routeFieldName: slug` instead of your 2 `routeField*` keys.
For performance, it is recommended to use `limitToPages: [yourPageUid]`. In order to remove potential ambiguity, it is recommended to add a prefix to `routePath`, for example `/dsmag/{name}` (this is not strictly required, but will make sure that only the desired routeEnhancer matches). Make sure that your `ElencocdsmagController::detailAction()` has an argument `$elencocds`.

Comment: @JonasEberle 
 : Thank you Thank you Thank you. You saved me.